# PL/pgSQL - %TYPE and ARRAY

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Is it possible to use the %TYPE and array together?

```
CREATE FUNCTION role_update(
  IN id "role".role_id % TYPE,
  IN name   "role".role_name % TYPE,
  IN user_id_list "user".user_id % TYPE[],
  IN permission_id_list  INT[]
)
```

I got syntax error by this, but I don't want to duplicate any column type, so I want to use `"user".user_id % TYPE` instead of simply `INT` because then it is easier to modify any column type later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the manual explains [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html):

> The type of a column is referenced by writing table_name.column_name%TYPE. Using this feature can sometimes help make a function independent of changes to the definition of a table.

The same functionality can be used in the `RETURNS` clause.

But there is no simple way to derive an array type from a referenced column, at least none that I would know of.

About `modifying any column type later`:
You are aware that this type of syntax is only a syntactical convenience to derive the type from a table column? Once created, there is **no link whatsoever** to the table or column involved.

It helps to keep a whole create script in sync. But id doesn't help with later changes to live objects in the database.

Related answer on dba.SE:

- [Array of template type in PL/pgSQL function using %TYPE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/130394/3684)

Comment: "You are aware that this type of syntax is only a syntactical convenience to derive the type from a table column?" - Yes I know.

Answer (score 5):

Using referenced types in function's parameters has no sense (in PostgreSQL), because its translated intermediately to actual types, and it is stored as actual types. Sorry, PostgreSQL doesn't support this functionality - something different is using referenced types inside function, where actual type is detected every first time execution in session.

Comment: It is perfectly valid, thou to use `%TYPE` in function's internal variables.

Comment: "has no sense" - it does have sense in that it helps with readability, same as `%TYPE` does.

Comment: @Meglio - in this case I am not sure. It can be an trap, because there is not real persistent dependency on source object. In this case (function's parameters) the syntax is same like Oracle, but behaviour is different. This case is really specific, and I don't know if this feature is good or bad.